# Unzip all files in a directory failing - IO::Uncompress Perl

Tags: perl, unzip, compression

I'm trying to unzip all files in a directory using [IO::Compress](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/FAQ.pod), but my script is failing with no error details.  I used [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Unzip) as a reference, and it seems pretty simple, but it just dies with:

```
root@test:/home/user# ./unzip.pl
Its there.
unzip failed:
```

```
my $outputdir = "/tmp";
if ( <$outputdir/*.zip> ){
    print "Its there.\n";
    unzip '<$outputdir/*.zip>' => '<$outputdir/#1>'
    or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";
}
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported the variable as shown in the Synopsis?

Comment: Vars won't be interpolated inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out the code and syntax. Basically, the syntax is:

1. Open the zip file.
2. While you read in the next file stream (`nextStream`).

   1. Find the name of the file stream you're reading.
   2. Create a new file to write to (using `open` or `File::IO->new`)
   3. While there is data in the file stream (`read`)

      1. Write to the new file's buffer.
   4. Close the file you created.
3. Close the zip file.

The trick is that the two `while` statements will return a status of less than zero (specifically a `-1`) if there is a problem with the reading. They return a status of zero when they are finished. Thus, right after the `while` statement, you've got to check the status.

This is the code I used. Notice I don't import `$UnzipError`, but instead, I use the full name of the variable including it's package name.

```
#
# Unzip Artifact
#
my $zip_fh = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new( $old_zip_file )
    or die qq(Cannot open zip "$old_zip_file" for reading.);
#
# Go through each element in Zip file
#
while ( my $status = $zip_fh->nextStream ) {
    if ( $status < 0 ) {
        die qq(Error in Zip: $IO::Uncompress::Unzip::UnzipError.);
    }
    #
    # Get name of the file you're unzipping in the zip
    #
    my $element_name = $zip_fh->getHeaderInfo->{Name};
    next if $element_name =~ m{/$};      # Skip Directories
    my $element_dir = dirname $element_name;
    my $full_element_dir = File::Spec->join( $unzip_directory, $element_dir );
    #
    # Create the directory for the file if it doesn't exist
    #
    my $full_element_name = File::Spec->join( $unzip_directory, $element_name );
    if ( not -d $full_element_dir ) {
        make_path $full_element_dir
            or die qq(Can't make directory "$full_element_dir".);
    }
    my $unzipped_fh = IO::File->new( $full_element_name, "w" )
        or die qq(Can't open file "$full_element_name" for writing: $!);
    #
    # Now repeatably read the file until you've written everything
    #
    my $buffer;
    while ( my $status = $zip_fh->read( $buffer ) ) {
        if ( $status < 0 ) {
            die qq(Error in Zip: $IO::Uncompress::Unzip::UnzipError.);
        }
        $unzipped_fh->write( $buffer );
    }
    $unzipped_fh->close;
}
$zip_fh->close;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError) ;

for my $input ( glob "/tmp/*.zip" )
{
    my $output = $input;
    $output =~ s/.zip// ;
    unzip $input => $output or die "Error compressing '$input': $UnzipError\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix that was suggested by David W. 82.2k25154274 (see below) had a small bug.
Great example and I copied it, but it always ignored one file! 
Fix is to initialize $status to 1 and only call next at end of loop.

Fix:

```
#
# Unzip Artifact
#
my $zip_fh = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new( $old_zip_file )
    or die qq(Cannot open zip "$old_zip_file" for reading.);
#
# Go through each element in Zip file
#
my $status = 1;
while ( $status ) {
    if ( $status < 0 ) {
        die qq(Error in Zip: $IO::Uncompress::Unzip::UnzipError.);
    }
    #
    # Get name of the file you're unzipping in the zip
    #
    my $element_name = $zip_fh->getHeaderInfo->{Name};
    next if $element_name =~ m{/$};      # Skip Directories
    my $element_dir = dirname $element_name;
    my $full_element_dir = File::Spec->join( $unzip_directory, $element_dir );
    #
    # Create the directory for the file if it doesn't exist
    #
    my $full_element_name = File::Spec->join( $unzip_directory, $element_name );
    if ( not -d $full_element_dir ) {
        make_path $full_element_dir
            or die qq(Can't make directory "$full_element_dir".);
    }
    my $unzipped_fh = IO::File->new( $full_element_name, "w" )
        or die qq(Can't open file "$full_element_name" for writing: $!);
    #
    # Now repeatably read the file until you've written everything
    #
    my $buffer;
    while ( my $status = $zip_fh->read( $buffer ) ) {
        if ( $status < 0 ) {
            die qq(Error in Zip: $IO::Uncompress::Unzip::UnzipError.);
        }
        $unzipped_fh->write( $buffer );
    }
    $unzipped_fh->close;

    $status = $zip_fh->nextStream; # Getting next file if any... or 0 to quit loop...
}
$zip_fh->close;
```